# Is is possible that a shooting range is the whole court?

Tags: kuroko-no-basket

In Kuroko no Basket's Episode 12 , Midorima said that his shooting range was the entire court. Can this happen in real life?

[image]

Comment: Having ridiculous sports abilities is common in sports anime/manga (see Prince of Tennis).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basketball, and doesn't require any knowledge of the anime in question to answer.

Comment: Or the better question: Is it possible to do HALF of the things they do there? (like a spontaneous nitro or having byakugan in real life). Well I guess not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

His shooting range isn't the entire court. I haven't watched the anime, but I have read the latest manga and his consistent shooting range is around half court. His statement is probably a bluff in this case.

No one can frequently hit shots from full or half court in basketball, it is simply too far. Most people throw the ball from those distances, because shooting doesn't have enough power to go that far. And throwing the ball means you are just lunging it, without aiming.

EDIT:

If you can hit a shot from full court range, you dont even have to pass in the ball. You can just throw it from there.